# Prolog (SWI): Conjunction over a list?

Tags: list, prolog

Say I have a predicate eval(A) that just evaluates to true/false depending on some input

Now the thing is, I want another predicate 
**and(List, R)** 
that succeeds iff List is empty/the conjunction of the eval of every element in List is R. Where **R is just true/false**.

So if List had the items [a, b, c], then return [eval(a) ^ eval(b) ^ eval(c)] == R

My attempt:

```
and([], true).
and([H|T], R) :- eval(H), and(T, R).
and([H|T], R) :- eval(H) = R.
```

But i don't know how to compare to R properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog has a *relational* data model, predicates don't carry values. You must add an argument to eval/1, holding the 'return value'.

```
and([], true).
and([H|T], R) :-
 eval(H, X),  % could 'shortcircuit' to false here if X is false
 and(T, And),
 ( X == true, And == true -> R = true ; R = false ).
```

*edit* better could be, without changing eval/1:

```
and(L, R) :- 
   maplist(eval, L) -> R = true ; R = false.
```